# Extend a clean out in main line in basement

Tags: plumbing

I have a hole in my basement flooring where a clean out is for the main line. Does anyone have any recommendations on what to do with the clean out. The pipe is metal with a rubber stopper at the end.

[image]

Is it possible to extend the clean out with a vertical pipe and fill in the hole? or
Is it recommended to keep as is and just put a cover.

We are putting some carpet downstairs over the existing tile. The carpet will go up to the hole with a border of a few inches or so.

https://ibb.co/mX78od

https://ibb.co/bwKzuJ

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's pretty hard to see the clean-out opening; a better picture would likely get you a better answer.

Comment: i would get one of those little brass "trap door" hatch covers for it, like you see in stores and other commercial establishments; they look OK "floating" on carpet

Comment: Thanks @dandavis. I will look into that. I added some more photos.

Comment: you might consider a square register grate, like they used in old houses as cold-air returns, if you can find one the right size. Looking closer, even a board would make a nice cover, which you can carpet over, then slice open + trim-out with edging or leave carpeted-over until actually needed.